# IG - WTI Spot Price vs Future

Tags: futures, commodities, broker

I am a beginner and have a basic question.
I was looking at OIL - US Crude in IG today (20th of April), they have a spot and a future contract.

Today was the last trading day for May future contract. The future contract was trading at less than one dollar and the spot contract was trading at 20 USD, how does it works, I thought the future would converge to the spot price and would be equal to the spot price at maturity.

What I was looking in IG: [OIL - US Crude](https://www.ig.com/uk/marketanalysis/ig-commodities/us-light-crude)
I think it is tracking [NYMEX WTI](https://www.cmegroup.com/trading/energy/crude-oil/light-sweet-crude.html)

I didn't buy anything, I am just trying to understand.

What do they use for "OIL - US Crude" spot price, on NYMEX WTI I only find futures and no spot market, I don't understand the underlying and why the price is currently around 2200.

How does it works, why didn't the spot price drop more or the future go up ?

Thanks a lot for your help !

Comment: It is very important that you understand what you are actually trading if you are going to trade. So you have noticed that the two do not behave the same, I would recommend you ask ig index what the underlying is of you cannot see a clear explanation of what it is, and i would also recommend you not invest in anything if you do know what it is, or understand the risks it poses.

Comment: IG trades contracts for difference and spread bets. These are derived from the next two futures. This is not a way to trade spot, which btw was fully aligned today with the April settlement which just expired. IG does not trade spot.